# How to detect when a menu is rendered in tinymce 4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

In `tinymce 4`, the menu bar is rendered but each menu is rendered only on click.

To illustrate this, notice that each menu from the menu bar has the `mce-menu` class.

At any time, if no menu is open, if you try to get the set of menus, you'll fail because they aren't rendered yet:

```
var menuSet = $('.mce-menu');
// menuSet.length : 0
```

But if you click a menu bar header, let say the `insert` menu, it will be rendered and opened. Now, keeping it open, going to the console and retrying:

```
var menuSet = $('.mce-menu');
// menuSet.length : 1
```

and you'll get the opened menu.

Now if you close it clicking anywhere out of the opened menu, and retrying:

```
var menuSet = $('.mce-menu');
// menuSet.length : 1
```

... the menu is not removed from the DOM. It's a good news: since the menu was rendered once, we can get and manipulate it.

I have some DOM manipulation to do with each `.mce-menu` elements, but I'll have to now when each menu is opened the first time.

But **how to handle a such event ?**

I can't get any clue from the official documentation nor the forums, or anywhere.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem : I want to conditionnaly activate menu items based on what is currently happening in the editor.

I managed to intercept the click event on the document's body, but unfortunately, TinyMCE intercepts other events like focus, mouseenter and the like which I also need to work with.

The problem is that the app implements its own special way of managing and bubbling events, and I can't yet see a way to intervene in the process.

Comment: Hey, I forgotten that question... Since I posted it I found a good way to handle that. I'll post a complete answer here in few hours when I'll come back home.

Comment: @Countzero, I'm sorry for the delay. You can now read my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42773812/3197383

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by writting a convenient `Tinymce 4 plugin focused on that purpose.

Of course this plugin is open-sourced by the GNU GPL v2 license, following the original Tinymce licensing policy.

> **Tinymce Plugin MenusController:**
>
> https://github.com/sirap-group/tinymce-plugin-menuscontroller

But I didn't wrote the documentation yet, my apologies.

However, here is how you can use it:

## Install the plugin

Download the latest release tarball from github or, even better, install it from bower:

```
bower install tinymce-plugin-menuscontroller
```

If you don't know `bower`, discover it here: https://bower.io (`npm i -g bower; bower --help`).

The npm package isn't available yet, I'd provide it soon (but any Pull Request on github is welcome...).

By default, the plugin folder would be downoaded and placed in `./bower_components`. If you've installed tinymce the same way, you've got also `./bower_components/tinymce` or `./bower_components/tinymce-dist`.

You **don't need** to add the script to your `index.html` file because tinymce load it itself if you setup it correctly.

So you need to :

1. symlink it to the tinymce plugin folder:

   ```
   $ cd ./bower_components/tinymce/plugins
   $ ln -s ../../tinymce-plugin-menuscontroller menuscontroller
   ```
2. load it in tinymce init. For example:

   tinymce.init({
     selector: 'textarea',
     // [...]
     plugins: 'menuscontroller'
   })

## Get the plugin instance:

```
var editor = window.tinymce.activeEditor
var menusCtl = editor.plugins.menuscontroller
// at this point, if menusCtl is undefined, something gone wrong in the setup step: please check the previous steps.
```

## Plugin API (v0.2.1)

### Instance Methods

Get the menu bar:

```
menusCtl.getMenubar()
```

Get each menu by the name it was registered with:

```
menusCtl.getMenuByName(String: name)
```

Get the toolbars

```
menusCtl.getToolbars
```

### Events

#### Event: `menusController:mceMenuRendered` event

When any tinymce menu is rendered

```
$('body').on('menusController:mceMenuRendered', function (evt, menuDomNode) {
  console.log(menuDomNode)
})
```

> The `menusController:mceMenuRendered` event is called one for each menu of the active editor menubar, when it is rendered, so when the user click the dropdown menu (`File` link for the "file" menu, `Insert` for the "insert" menu, etc...).

#### Event: `menusController:mceMenuItemRendered:<menuDomID>`

When any menu item is rendered. Let's say we've created a menu item with the `my-custom-menu-item` identifier. So tinymce set its DOM ID to `my-custom-menu-item`. Thus, the MenusController plugin will create and bind to body the following event:

```
menusController:mceMenuItemRendered:my-custom-menu-item
```

So you can handle the rendered event of your custom menu item listening on it:

```
$('body').on('menusController:mceMenuItemRendered:my-custom-menu-item',
  function (evt, menuItemDomNode) {
    console.log(menuItemDomNode)
  }
)
```

## MenusController API (v0.3.0+)

> A the time of wrinting (Monday, mars the 13th, 2017), the last released version is the `v0.2.1`. But the `v0.3.0` is planned to be released soon, and will provide a new event, more useful than the last.

#### Event: `menusController:mceMenuItemRendered`

> When you need to know the menu item ID to handle the event `menusController:mceMenuItemRendered:<menuDomID>` and get the menu item DOM Node as callback argument, the event `menusController:mceMenuItemRendered` don't needs it but provides it as callback argument for each new rendered menu item:

```
$('body').on('menusController:mceMenuItemRendered',
  function (evt, menuItemID) {
    console.log(menuItemID) // 'my-custom-menu-item'

    // So you can hanlde all menu item even if you don't know its ID
    // And you can also handle the DOM Node with the selector by ID
    var selector = '#' + menuItemID
    var menuItem = $(selector)
    console.log(menuItem) // jQuery object (the menu item)
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible, but we both were not aware enough of how JS events are managed.

I tried to code my events handlers the old way :

```
$('body').on('click', function() { 
    do_stuff();
});
```

While I had to do it the new, correct way :

```
$('body').on('click', '.mce-btn', function() { 
    do_stuff();
});
```

With this, the events are correctly managed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use onPostrender funtion :

```
editor.addMenuItem("mybtn", {
    type: "menuitem",
    name: 'mybtn',
    onPostRender:function (){
        // write your code here//
    },
```

Answer (score -1):

With tinymce you can fully customize the menu buttons via the *editor* object:

```
tinymce.init({
  /*....*/
  setup: function(editor) {
    editor.addButton('mybutton', {
      type: 'menubutton',
      text: 'My button',
      icon: false,
      onclick: function(){
        alert('Some Message');
      },
      menu: [{
        text: 'Menu item 1',
        onclick: function() {
          alert('Some Message');
        }
      }]
    });
  }
 /*....*/
});
```

Unfortunately you cannot insert html inside the text property, but i think you can do that with more research. You can also create a callback function for the click event on the menu button.

Personally, I will use *tinymce* official api to modify the dom instead of doing some other event driven dom manipulation.

You can find more a good example [here](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/custom-toolbar-menu-button/)

Comment: Don't think this info is relevant as to what OP is trying to do : the question is about manipulating the menu AFTER initialization, so hinting at things happening at this stage doesn't help.

Comment: In my view it's never a safe/good idea to manipulate a javascript driven DOM listening to undocumented events. Especially in a complex plugin like tinyMce. 

This kind of things always backfires in unpredictable ways. 

Because the OP, didn't explain the kind of manipulation needed i suggested reading the official api to see if there was a way to achieve the same api through documented apis.

Comment: I can see where you come from, and definitely agree with the backfire problem. Still, some of us use TinyMCE in some weird ways (in my case, I try to make it manage XML/TEI markup) and need that kind of info. IMHO, it's up to the asking person to consider wether it's a good idea or not to try that kind of experiences. BTW, I'll post a solution below shortly.